# How do I grab images from JSON Data using AJAX JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Hi how do I use jquery with AJAX to grab images from a JSON file and display it on my page? Here's my code.

```
function bookSearch(){
  var search = document.getElementById('search').value;
  //Results innerHTML is an empty string, so it would be a new search each time.
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML= ""

  $.ajax ({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + search,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data){
      var results= document.getElementById('results');
      for(i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++){
        results.innerHTML += "<span class='col-md-4'>" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.title + "</span>"
        results.innerHTML += "<img class='col-md-4'>" + data.items[i].imageLinks.smallThumbnail + "</img>"

      }
    },
    type: 'GET'
  });
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', bookSearch, false)
```

Comment: Since you're using jQuery you don't need to use `document.getElementById`, you can use `$('#results').html('');` and for your search value `$('#search').val()` and for the button `$('#button').click(bookSearch);`

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the `src` property of the image HTML element.

```
results.innerHTML += "<img class='col-md-4' src='" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail + "'"
```

Following is a working implementation of the code. Also, note that i have manipulated the DOM using jquery.

1. Adding the `$(document).ready(function()` function, so that an event handler can be registered when the DOM has completely loaded.
2. To get the value from the textbox, use the `$('#search').val();` method.
3. Using the `$('#results').html('')` method to set the innerHTML.
4. Added validation to handle scenarios where the image link is not included in the reponse.
5. Added the event handler using jquery `on` method, `$("#button").on("click", bookSearch);`
6. The `smallThumbnail` property should be accessed as `data.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail` and not as `data.items[i].imageLinks.smallThumbnail`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

function bookSearch(){
  var search = $('#search').val();
  //Results innerHTML is an empty string, so it would be a new search each time.
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML= ""

  $.ajax ({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + search,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data){
      var innerHTML = "";
      for(var i=0; i < data.items.length; i++){
        
  if(data.items[i].volumeInfo.title && data.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks &&
   data.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail){
  innerHTML += "<span class='col-md-4' title='>" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.title + "'</span>" +
         "<img class='col-md-4' src='" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail + "'>";
  }
    }
 $('#results').html(innerHTML);
      
    },
    type: 'GET'
  });
}
$("#button").on("click", bookSearch);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="text"/>

<button id="button">image</button>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Your first code snippet still needs to be updated. Should be `data.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail`.

Comment: @Press, thanks for the comment, yeah i didn't update that, will do it now.

Comment: No problem. In his original code that line was the only erroneous line that needed to be fixed for it to work.

Comment: "<img id='img' class='col-md-4' src='" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail + "'>"

WORKED. Thanks :))))

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are on the correct track.  However the 'img' tag requires you to specify the 'src' to display the image.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
for(i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++){
        results.innerHTML += "<span class='col-md-4'>" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.title + "</span>"
        results.innerHTML += "<img class='col-md-4' src='" + data.items[i].imageLinks.smallThumbnail + "'/>"
}
```

Comment: this is what shows up on the console when I try yours.


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'smallThumbnail' of undefined
    at Object.success (main.js:25)
    at fire (jquery-3.1.1.js:3305)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.js:3435)
    at done (jquery-3.1.1.js:9242)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.js:9484)

Comment: This is just a parsing error.  In the JSON response, the object to be retrieved is actually "data.items[i].imageLinks.smallThumbnail", since 'imageLinks' is a JSON Object containing 'smallThumbnail' and 'thumbnail'.

Comment: It needs to be `data.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail` not `data.items[i].imageLinks.smallThumbnail`.